# Adding confirm email field to entityform

Tags: 7, entities

I am using [email field module](https://drupal.org/project/email) and entityform for a simple contact form on a Drupal 7 install. I need to add an extra field where the user re-enters their email address (no copy and paste) to prevent typos.

This seems like a simple enough requirement so I'm wondering if I'm just overlooking something in entityform or email field that will help me do this, or perhaps an additional module?

Can anyone recommend a method to achieve this?

Plan B is to use jquery.

Thanks!

Comment: How about adding second email field and using it only for some custom made JavaScript which will just check if both fields have same values when form is submitted and cancel form submission if they are different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CCK Match](https://drupal.org/project/cck_match) to achieve this goal.

Comment: CCK Match is for Drupal 6, Entityform is only for Drupa l 7

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing this out. I've edited my original question to specify I'm using Drupal 7.